# Блок меню не растягивается по ширине

Tags: html, css

Не получается сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении экрана блок меню и футер были по всей ширине экрана

```css
#wrap {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.725);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
}

#window {
  width: 400px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #008D27;
}

.close {
  margin-left: 364px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
.sitebar_header {
  color: #FF7D1E;
}

h3 {
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008D27
}

.clearAll {
  clear: both;
}

#wrapper {
  min-width: 1180px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header_wrap {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#header_top {
  height: 120px;
  width: 82%;
  min-width: 1180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.logo_two {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.socials_ico>li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.socials_ico {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  right: 104px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

#menu_top_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFEEE1;
}

#menu_top {
  width: 82%;
  background: #FFEEE1;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #008D27;
  min-width: 1180px;
}

.menu_top_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  background: #FFEEE1;
  position: relative;
}

#menu_top ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 46px;
}

#menu_top li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#menu_top > ul> a> li:hover {
  color: #FF7D1E !important;
}

.tel {
  font-size: 36px;
  float: right;
  color: #008d27;
}

.tel_desc {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #FF7D1E;
  float: right;
}

.my-slider {
  min-width: 1180px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
  width: 65%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
}

#sitebar_l {
  width: 224px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 1800px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.sitebar_header {
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FFEEE1;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul.categories_sitebar {
  list-style: square;
  color: #008D27;
  margin-left: 28px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

ul.categories_sitebar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008D27;
}

ul.categories_sitebar>li>a:hover {
  color: #FF7D1E;
}

ul.categories_sitebar>li {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  color: #FF7D1E;
}

#main_content {
  min-width: 940px;
  background: #fff;
}

#main_text {}

.main_h1,
.main_par {}

.main_h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.text_zakaz {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #FF7D1E;
  font-style: italic;
}

#doctors_block {
  min-width: 940px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.online_zakaz {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #008D27;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.online_zakaz:hover {
  background: #ff7d1e none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.top_zakaz {
  position: absolute;
  right: 112px;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: 46px;
}

.action_img {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.action_img:hover {
  border: 3px solid #008D27;
}

.action_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 190px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.doctors_list {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*
.hr{

     border: 1px dotted #DADADA;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 900px;
}
*/

.doctors_list > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.doctors_list >li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.doctors_list > li >img {
  width: 180px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.doctors_list > li >img:hover {
  border: 2px solid #008D27;
}

#news_block {
  height: 225px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 940px;
}

.news_item {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  min-width: 260px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 270px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.news_item:hover {
  border: 3px solid #008D27;
  border-left: 3px solid #008D27;
  border-right: 3px solid #008D27;
}

.news_prew_text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.news_h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.news_h3:hover {
  color: #008D27;
}

.news_date {
  background: #ff7d1e none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  float: right;
}

#programs_block {
  min-width: 940px;
  height: 190px;
  background: #FFEEE1;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.programs_header {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.programs_item {
  width: 415px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.programs_item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #008D27;
}

.program_prew_img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.program_prew_h3 {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  color: #008D27;
}

.second_prog {
  float: left;
}

.all_programs_link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.all_programs_link:hover {
  color: #FF7D1E;
}

#footer {
  background: #E7E7E8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu_footer {
  margin-left: 113px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu_footer > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu_footer > ul>a>li {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.menu_footer ul:first-child {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.footer_text {
  margin-right: 112px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#foot_wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 82%;
  min-width: 1180px;
}

.foot_ico {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}

.bw {
  color: #606060;
}

.map {
  float: right;
}


/* ----------------------------------TOP BUTTON */

#toTop {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 100%;
  background: url(../images/ui.totop.png) no-repeat left top;
}

#toTopHover {
  background: url(../images/ui.totop.png) no-repeat left -51px;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#toTop:active,
#toTop:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* ---------------------------------TOP BUTTON END */


/*---------------------------------------SLIDER CSS START-----------------*/

.slider {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 1199px;
  height: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 7px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.slider ul,
.slider li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slider ul {
  width: 9999px;
}

.slider ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 1199px;
  height: 290px;
}

.slider .nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

.slider .nav span {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}

.slider .nav span.on {
  background: #2e9419;
}


/*---------------------------------------SLIDER CSS-----------------*/


/*---------------------------------------CONTACTS-----------------*/

#feedback-form {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#feedback-form [required] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px 0 2% 0;
  padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset, 0 0 transparent;
}

#feedback-form [required]:hover {
  border-color: #7eb4ea;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset, 0 0 transparent;
}

#feedback-form [required]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #7eb4ea;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset, 0 0 4px rgba(35, 146, 243, .5);
  transition: .2s linear;
}

#feedback-form [type="submit"] {
  padding: 2%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset;
  background: #669acc;
  color: #fff;
}

#feedback-form [type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #5c90c2;
}

#feedback-form [type="submit"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

  <head>


    <script type="Text/Javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sudoSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- UItoTop plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Starting the plugin -->
    <title>(X)HTML+CSS код шаблона</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Функция показа
      function show(state) {

        document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;
        document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="window">

        <!-- Картинка крестика-->
        <!--<img class="close" onclick="show('none')" src="http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/close.png">-->

        <form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
          Как к Вам обращаться:
          <input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="фамилия имя отчество" x-autocompletetype="name"> Email для связи:
          <input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="адрес электронной почты" x-autocompletetype="email"> Ваш телефон:
          <input name="telFF" required placeholder="например, 89000000000" x-autocompletetype="tel" type="tel"> К какому врачу записываетесь:
          <input name="docFF" required placeholder="ФИО врача или специализация" x-autocompletetype="tel" type="tel"> Ваше сообщение:
          <textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="отправить">
        </form>

        <script>
          document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
              f = this;
            evt.preventDefault();
            http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.send("nameFF=" + f.nameFF.value + "&contactFF=" + f.contactFF.value + "&messageFF=" + f.messageFF.value + "&telFF=" + f.telFF.value + "&docFF=" + f.docFF.value);
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText + ', Ваше сообщение получено.\nНаши специалисты ответят Вам в течении 2-х дней.\nБлагодарим за интерес к нашей фирме!');
                f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); // очистить поле сообщения (две строки)
                f.messageFF.value = '';
              }
            }
            http.onerror = function() {
              alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
            }
          }, false);

        </script>
        </center>

      </div>

      <div id="header_top">

        <img src="images/logo.png" width="470" height="103">
        <img class="logo_two" src="images/logo2.png" width="337" height="103">
        <span class="tel">+(993)348998325<br><span class="tel_desc">горячая линия</span></span>
        <ul class="socials_ico">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/youtube.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/vkontakte.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="clearAll"></div>
      <div class="menu_top_wrap">
        <div id="menu_top">
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Услуги</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>О нас</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Цены</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Врачи</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Пациентам</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Акции</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Программы</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Вопрос-Ответ</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Контакты</li>
            </a>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <a href="#"><span  onclick="show('block')" class="myButton online_zakaz top_zakaz">ЗАПИСЬ НА ПРИЕМ</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearAll"></div>


      <div class="slider_wrap">

        <div class="slider">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="image description" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="image description" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="image description" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide2.png" alt="image description" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="image description" /></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="clearAll"></div>

      <div id="sitebar_l">

        <span class="sitebar_header">Наши услуги</span>

        <ul class="categories_sitebar">
          <li><a href="#">Хирургия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Дерматология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Педиатрия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Стомотология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Лаборатория</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Педиатрия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Дерматология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Стомотология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Педиатрия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Стомотология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Лаборатория</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Педиатрия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Дерматология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Стомотология</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Лаборатория</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Педиатрия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Дерматология</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="sitebar_header">Наши акции</span>

        <a href="#"><img class="action_img" src="images/act1.jpg" width="180" height="140" alt="текст" title="title">
          <span class="action_title">Давно выяснено, чт выяснено, чт выяснено, что при</span></a>

        <a href="#"><img class="action_img" src="images/act2.jpg" width="180" height="140" alt="текст" title="title">
          <span class="action_title">Давно выяснено, что но, что при</span></a>
      </div>
      <div id="content">



        <div id="main_content">
          <div id="main_text">
            <h1 class="main_h1">Давно выяснено</h1>
            <p class="main_par">Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в
              абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.." Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в качестве текста по умолчанию, так что поиск по ключевым
              словам "lorem ipsum" сразу показывает, как много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего настоящего рождения. За прошедшие годы текст Lorem Ipsum получил много версий. Некоторые версии появились по ошибке, некоторые - намеренно (например,
              юмористические варианты).</p>
            <br/>
            <p class="main_par">Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в
              абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.." Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в качестве текста по умолчанию, так что поиск по ключевым
              словам "lorem ipsum" сразу показывает, как много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего настоящего рождения. За прошедшие годы текст Lorem Ipsum получил много версий. Некоторые версии появились по ошибке, некоторые - намеренно (например,
              юмористические варианты).</p>
            <br/>
            <p class="main_par">Б</p>
            <br/>
            <p class="main_par">Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в
              абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.." Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в качестве текста по умолчанию, так что поиск по ключевым
              словам "lorem ipsum" сразу показывает, как много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего настоящего рождения. За прошедшие годы текст Lorem Ipsum получил много версий. Некоторые версии появились по ошибке, некоторые - намеренно (например,
              юмористические варианты).</p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="doctors_block">
            <h2>Наши врачи</h2>

            <ul class="doctors_list">
              <li class="view"><img src="images/doc1.jpg"></li>

              <li class="view"><img src="images/doc2.jpg"></li>
              <li class="view"><img src="images/doc3.png
      "></li>
              <li class="end_block_doct"><img src="images/doc4.jpg"></li>
            </ul>

            <span class="text_zakaz">Вы можете записаться на прием к нашим специалистам</span>

            <a href="#"><span class="online_zakaz">ЗАПИСЬ НА ПРИЕМ</span></a>
          </div>

          <div id="news_block">
            <h2>Новости клиники</h2>

            <div class="news_item">
              <span class="news_date">12/33/22</span>
              <h3 class="news_h3">Заголовок новостиfbfgfsg  g rzg rga</h3>

              <span class="news_prew_text">много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего 
                      настоящего рождения</span>
              <a href="#">Подробнее</a>

            </div>
            <div class="news_item">
              <span class="news_date">12/33/22</span>
              <h3 class="news_h3">Заголовок новости</h3>
              <span class="news_prew_text">много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего 
                      настоящего рождения</span>
              <a href="#">Подробнее</a>

            </div>
            <div class="news_item">
              <h3 class="news_h3">Заголовок новости</h3>
              <span class="news_prew_text">много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего 
                      настоящего рождения</span>
              <a href="#">Подробнее</a>

            </div>


          </div>
          <div id="prog_wrap">
            <h2 class="programs_header">Программы клиники</h2>
            <div id="programs_block">

              <div class="programs_item">
                <img class="program_prew_img" src="images/prog1.png" width="70" height="70">
                <h3 class="program_prew_h3">Заголовок программы</h3>
                <span class="programs_prew_txt">много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего 
                      настоящего рождения</span>

              </div>

              <div class="programs_item second_prog">
                <img class="program_prew_img" src="images/prog2.png" width="70" height="70">
                <h3 class="program_prew_h3">Заголовок программы два</h3>
                <span class="programs_prew_txt">много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего 
                      настоящего рождения</span>

              </div>
              <a class="all_programs_link" href="#">все программы</a>
            </div>



          </div>

        </div>



      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <div class="menu_footer">
          <ul class="first_foot_menu">
            <a href="#">
              <li>Услуги</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>О нас</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Цены</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Врачи</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Пациентам</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Акции</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Программы</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Вопрос-Ответ</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Контакты</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
          <ul class="socials_ico foot_ico">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/youtube.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/youtube.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img class="soc_img" src="images/vkontakte.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <span class="footer_text" style="color:#4C4C4C">Все права защищены.<span> Клиника семейной медицины</span>

        </div>

        <hr>
        <div id="foot_wrap">
          <img src="images/logo_bw.png" width="470" height="103">
          <img class="logo_two" src="images/logo2_bw.png" width="337" height="103">
          <span class="tel bw">+(993)348998325<br><span class="tel_desc bw">горячая линия</span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        var defaults = {
        containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
        containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
        scrollSpeed: 1200,
        easingType: 'linear'
        };
        */

        $().UItoTop({
          easingType: 'easeOutQuart'
        });

      });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slider").each(function() {

          var repeats = 5, // кількість повторювань автоматичного прокручування
            interval = 2, // інтервал в секундах
            repeat = true, // чи треба автоматично прокручувати (true/false)
            slider = $(this),
            repeatCount = 0,
            elements = $(slider).find("li").length;

          $(slider)
            .append("<div class='nav'></div>")
            .find("li").each(function() {
              $(slider).find(".nav").append("<span data-slide='" + $(this).index() + "'></span>");
              $(this).attr("data-slide", $(this).index());
            })
            .end()
            .find("span").first().addClass("on");

          // add timeout

          if (repeat) {
            repeat = setInterval(function() {
              if (repeatCount >= repeats - 1) {
                window.clearInterval(repeat);
              }

              var index = $(slider).find('.on').data("slide"),
                nextIndex = index + 1 < elements ? index + 1 : 0;

              sliderJS(nextIndex, slider);

              repeatCount += 1;
            }, interval * 4000);
          }

        });
      });

      function sliderJS(index, slider) { // slide
        var ul = $(slider).find("ul"),
          bl = $(slider).find("li[data-slide=" + index + "]"),
          step = $(bl).width();

        $(slider)
          .find("span").removeClass("on")
          .end()
          .find("span[data-slide=" + index + "]").addClass("on");

        $(ul).animate({
          marginLeft: "-" + step * index
        }, 2000);
      }

      $(document).on("click", ".slider .nav span", function(e) { // slider click navigate
        e.preventDefault();
        var slider = $(this).closest(".slider"),
          index = $(this).data("slide");

        sliderJS(index, slider);
      });

    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: я не вижу ваш отве, почемуто

Comment: Наведите порядок в коде и вам самому будет очевидно в чем дело. Сейчас у вас просто бардак.

Comment: согласен) Но по вопросу поможете?

Comment: Я вижу что у вас первоочередная проблема не в тех блоках о которых вы говорите. Но если вы настаиваете на ответе предлагаю для начала удались весь код, который не относится к сути дела.

Comment: удалил, посмотрите?

Comment: что-то не вижу никаких изменений...

Comment: проверьте ещё раз пожалуйста

Comment: Набросал вам небольшой адаптивный концепт - http://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/WxPBoE

Comment: Спасибо, буду переделывать под ваш пример

Comment: Видимо мой код-не годится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас многим элементам задана min-width: 1180px, что не позволяет адаптироваться меню. 
Дальше слайдеру `.slider` и элементам в нем у вас задана ширина и он сильно растягивает контейнер.

Добавте стили и увидете все проблемы.

```
<style>
* {
    min-width: inherit!important;
    }
.slider{
    display: none; 
    }   
</style>
```

И вообще почитайте вот эту статью о прогрессивной верстке если не значете что это, то в будущем вам очень сильно облегчит жизнь. https://habrahabr.ru/post/157115/